# How do I add data to another organization's Salesforce account using SOAP API?

Tags: soap-api

I need to add data, specifically a lead, to another organization's Salesforce account. I need to use the SOAP API from an external .NET web application.

In my prototypes I have the Enterprise WSDL in my Visual Studio project and I can successfully add a lead to my organization's Salesforce account, authenticating with my email address and password/security token combination.

However, I need to insert a lead into another organization's Salesforce account. The configuration (email, password, token etc) will be stored in the external .NET application, but the part I am struggling to understand is:

I have the Enterprise WSDL which is strongly typed to my organization's Salesforce account, so I cannot use that to make calls on another organization's Salesforce data, even if I have the credentials, correct?

This is how I am currently adding a lead to our Salesforce account

```
private SforceService binding;
binding = new SforceService();
binding.Timeout = 10000;
LoginResult lr = null;
bool success = true;

try
{
    lr = binding.login("myemailaddress", "mypasswordandtoken");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     success = false;
}
if(success)
{
    // snip, newLead is created here.
    SaveResult[] sr = binding.create(new sObject[] { newLead });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the partner WSDL to connect and update records in the other orgs:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner_objects.htm

> With the partner WSDL, your client application code handles fields as
>   arrays of name-value pairs that represent the field data. When
>   referring to the name of an individual field, use the value in its
>   name field of the Field type in the DescribeSObjectResult

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004760&language=en_US

> Salesforce provides a WSDL (Web Service Description Language) files.
>   They are called "Enterprise WSDL" and "Partner WSDL". A WSDL is an
>   XML-document which contains a standardized description on how to
>   communicate using a web service (the Salesforce API is exposed as a
>   web service). The WSDL is used by developers to aid in the creation of
>   Salesforce integration pieces. A typical process involves using the
>   Development Environment (eg, Eclipse for Java, or Visual Studio for
>   .Net) to consume the WSDL, and generate classes which are then
>   referenced in the integration.
>
> **Enterprise WSDL:**
>
> The Enterprise WSDL is strongly typed.
>
> - The Enterprise WSDL is tied (bound) to a specific configuration of    Salesforce (ie. a specific organization's Salesforce configuration).
> - The Enterprise WSDL changes if modifications (e.g custom fields or custom objects) are made to an organization's Salesforce
>     configuration.
>
> For the reasons outlined above, the Enterprise WSDL is intended
>   primarily for Customers.
>
> **Partner WSDL:**
>
> - The Partner WSDL is loosely typed.
> - The Partner WSDL can be used to reflect against/interrogate any configuration of Salesforce (ie. any organization's Salesforce
>     configuration).
> - The Partner WSDL is static, and hence does not change if modifications are made to an organization's Salesforce configuration.